# Creating an XML Element with <Element behavior = "replace"> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Im trying to recreate an xml where the result should look something like this:

```
<names>
    <legalName behavior="replace">
      <firstName>Value</firstName>
      <surName>Value</surName>
      <fullName>Value</fullName>
      <effDate>Value</effDate>
    </legalName>
  </names>
```

I have a attribute list that looks like this:

```
public class Names
{

    [XmlElement("legalName")]
    public LegalName LegalName { get; set; }
}

public class LegalName
{
    [XmlElement("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("surName")]
    public string SurName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fullName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("effDate")]
    public string EffDate { get; set; }
}
```

And logic :

```
foreach (var people in model.Peoples)
        {
            exportResult.Persons.Person.Add(new Person
            {

                Names = new Names()
                {
                    LegalName = new LegalName()
                    {
                        FirstName = people.LegalNameFirstName,
                        SurName = people.LegalNameSurName,
                        FullName = people.LegalNameFullName,
                        EffDate = people.LegalNameEffectiveDate
                    }
                }
             }
         }

     XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExportResult));
        StringWriter sww = new Utf8StringWrite();
        var xml = string.Empty; // Your XML
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, new XmlWriterSettings {Encoding = Encoding.UTF8}))
        {
            xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, exportResult);
            xml = sww.ToString();
        }
        return xml;
```

I want to know how to create this element:

```
<legalName behavior="replace">
```

Should i change the XmlElement in my attribute class? To something like:

```
public class Names
 {

[XmlElement("legalName"), XmlAttribute("behavior =\"replace\"")]
public LegalName LegalName { get; set; }
 }
```

How can i make a legalName element with behavior="replace" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a property as an attribute you'll need to add the XmlAttribute attribute to the property within its parent (similar to adding child elements).  So in your case:

```
public class Names
{
    [XmlElement("legalName")]
    public LegalName LegalName { get; set; }
}

public class LegalName
{
    [XmlElement("firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("surName")]
    public string SurName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fullName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("effDate")]
    public string EffDate { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("behavior")]
    public string Behavior { get; set; }
}
```